# Django Efficiency For Data Manipulation

Tags: python, django

I am doing some data changes in a django app with a large amount of data and would like to know if there is a way to make this more efficient. It's currently taking a really long time.

I have a model that used to look like this (simplified and changed names):

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    ... some fields...
    stuff = models.JSONField(encoder=DjangoJSONEncoder, default=list, blank=True)
```

I need to split the list up based on a new model.

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Thing(models.Model):
    .... some fields ...
    stuff = models.JSONField(encoder=DjangoJSONEncoder, default=list, blank=True)
    other_stuff = models.JSONField(encoder=DjangoJSONEncoder, default=list, blank=True)
    tags = models.Many2ManyField(Tag)
```

What I need to do is take the list that is currently in stuff, and split it up. For items that have a tag in the Tag model, add it to the Many2Many. For things that don't have a Tag, I add it to other_stuff. Then in the end, the stuff field should contain of the items that were saved in tags.

I start by looping through the Tags to make a dict that maps the string version that would be in the stuff list to the tag object so I don't have to keep querying the Tag model.

Then I loop through the Thing model, get the stuff field, loop through that and add each Tag item to the many2many while keeping lists for each item that is or isn't in Tags. Then put those in the stuff and other stuff fields at the end.

```
tags = Tag.objects.all()
tag_dict = {tag.name.lower():Tag for tag in tags}
things = Thing.objects.all()
for thing in things:
    stuff_list = thing.stuff
    stuff_in_tags = []
    stuff_not_in_tags = []
    for item in stuff_list:
        if item.lower() in tag_dict.keys():
             stuff_in_tags.append(item)
             thing.tags.add(tag_dict[item.lower()])
        else:
             stuff_not_in_tags.append(item)
    thing.stuff = stuff_in_tags
    thing.other_stuff = stuff_not_in_tags
    thing.save()
```

(Ignore any typos. This code works in my actual code)

That seems pretty efficient to me, but its taking hours to run as our database is pretty big (about 500k+ records). Are there any other ways to make this more efficient?

Comment: Off the top of my head, one thing you can add to improve the performance is to use [bulk update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update) for `things`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you move some work to the database level with bulk operations, it won't run faster. You are making at least N (500k+) `UPDATE` queries.

If the parsing cannot be done on the DB level, chunked bulk_update is the next option.

Also, you can use `iterator()` to avoid loading all the objects to memory and `only()` to load only relevant columns.

There is a typo in `tag_dict` - it should be `: tag` (instance) instead of `: Tag` (model).

EDIT: I've originally missed the `thing.tags.add` - this will need additional handling. You have to `bulk_create` m2m table rows.

```
chunk_size = 10000
TagsToThing = Thing.tags.through
tag_dict = {tag.name.lower():tag for tag in Tag.objects.all()}

for_update = []
tags_for_create = []
for thing in Thing.objects.only('pk', 'stuff').iterator(chunk_size):
    stuff_in_tags = []
    stuff_not_in_tags = []
    for item in thing.stuff:
        if item.lower() in tag_dict.keys():
             stuff_in_tags.append(item)
             tags_for_create.append(
                 TagsToThing(thing=thing, tag=tag_dict[item.lower()])
             )
        else:
             stuff_not_in_tags.append(item)

    thing.stuff = stuff_in_tags
    thing.other_stuff = stuff_not_in_tags
    for_update.append(thing)

    if len(for_update) == chunk_size:
        Thing.objects.bulk_update(for_update, ['stuff', 'other_stuff'], chunk_size)
        TagsToThing.objects.bulk_create(tags_for_create, ignore_conflicts=True)  # in case the tag is already assigned
        for_update = []
        tags_for_create = []

# Save remaining objects
Thing.objects.bulk_update(for_update, ['stuff', 'other_stuff'], chunk_size)
TagsToThing.objects.bulk_create(tags_for_create, ignore_conflicts=True)  # in case the tag is already assigned
```

Comment: @lovefaithswing how fast does it run now?

Comment: This is much faster! Did the whole database in 20 mins.